# Banach fixed point theorem (application)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach Spaces, and $T: X \to Y$, where T is continuous, linear and bijective, and let $S: X \to Y$ (where $S$ is continuous and linear) with $|S|\cdot|T^{-1}|< 1$. Show that $S+T$ is bijective. (Hint: Use Banach fixed point theorem)

This question was in my test today. I live in Brazil, so sorry for my English.

Comment: Did you mean $T:X\to X$ or $S:X\to Y$ or something similar? As it is $T+S$ isn't well defined.

Comment: No, the command is right. In the test, the professor commented that S+T: X -- > X + Y , where X+Y:={x+y; x belong to X and y belong to Y}

Comment: Okay. But then you have to specify $S+T$ is a bijection between $X$ and what? It can't be $X+Y$ (take $S=0$).

Comment: I understand. Indeed, this question created a big discution in the class, anyone in the class solved the question. Maybe the professtor is wrong. But, she ensures that there is a solution and show us on Monday

Comment: Please post her answer when you get it. I'd be very interested in what she has in mind. One last remark: In $X+Y$ we have that $T+S(x)=0_{X+Y}$ if and only if (as long as the sum $X+Y$ is an external direct sum) $T(x)=0_Y$ and $S(x)=0_X$. Since $T$ is bijective we get that $x=0_X$. We conclude that $S+T$ is one-to-one onto its image.

Comment: The professor was wrong.  She sent an email saying to consider X = Y

Comment: What do the premises imply about $(S+T)\circ T^{-1}$? Do you remember something vaguely similar?

Answer (score 1):

If $X=Y$ in your question, we have
\begin{equation*}
S+T: X \rightarrow X.
\end{equation*}

$S+T$ is a injective map, because $(S+T)(x) = 0 \Rightarrow x= 0 $.

Now, we want to show that for all $y \in X$, exists $x \in X$ such that $(S+T)(x)=y$. See that,
\begin{equation*}
(S+T)(x) = y \Leftrightarrow S(x) +T(x) =y \Leftrightarrow T^{-1}(y) - T^{-1}S(x) = x  
\end{equation*}
Set, $A(x) = T^{-1}(y) - T^{-1}S(x)$. It's easy to show that $A$ is a contraction, then $S+T$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$
S+T=T(I+T^{-1}S).
$$
Define
$$
K=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (T^{-1}S)^n\right)T^{-1}.
$$
Then, the series above converges as $\|T^{-1}S\|<1$, and hence
 $K$ is a bounded linear operator, and is readily shown that 
$$
K(S+T)=I.$$